# Как передать List на страницу jsp?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

У меня вот такой работающий контроллер:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Ура!");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Работает!");
        DataFromBase dataFromBase = new DataFromBase();
        List<Book> bookList = dataFromBase.getBooks();
        model.addAttribute("bookList",bookList); <- вот попытка передать Лист на jsp
        return "index";
    }

}
```

и так как это мой первый опыт со спрингом, то вот таким образом я получаю List из MySQL при помощи Hibernate:

```
public class DataFromBase {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("well/dao/hibernate.cfg.xml");

            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Ooops 1: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        final Session session = getSession();
        List<Book> bookList = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
            final Metamodel metamodel = session.getSessionFactory().getMetamodel();
            for (EntityType<?> entityType : metamodel.getEntities()) {
                final String entityName = entityType.getName();
                final Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityName);
                System.out.println("executing: " + query.getQueryString());
                bookList = query.list();
                for (Object o : bookList) {
                    System.out.println("  " + o);
                }
            }
            return bookList;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

ну и собственно сам jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Заголовок: ${title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Сообщение: ${message}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>author</th>
                <th>isbn</th>
                <th>printYear</th>
                <th>readAlready</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="book" items="${bookList}">
                <td>${book.id}</td>
                <td>${book.title}</td>
                <td>${book.description}</td>
                <td>${book.author}</td>
                <td>${book.isbn}</td>
                <td>${book.printYear}</td>
                <td>${book.readAlready}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

но фокус не удается...
как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Вы правильно объявили сам Jsp? По-моему там вверху ещё что то нужно объявить

Comment: верно, не хватало: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Answer (score 0):

верно, не хватало:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/235779)

Comment: Так товарищ оставил не ответ, а комментарий.

Comment: Я свой ответ создал, чтоб отметить его как правильный, так мне система говорит , что только через 2 дня я смогу свой ответ отметить как правильный... жду )